# Android: EditText design

Tags: android, image, android-layout, user-interface

I have an EditText view which I need to look like below (focused and non-focused versions).

[image]

[image]

Also I have two following images:

[image]
[image]

Can I somehow just set these images as a background to make EditText look like above, not depending on its width? Or do I need to create some additional image files? Or some other solution? I'm a complete newbie in designing UI, so I'd appreciate any help and any comments on subject.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first need to create a 9-patch graphic for each of your images. These specify how the image is stretched, and how the content is padded.

Then, you need to create a `selector` xml drawable to use one image or the other, based on the `EditText` state.